Strikethrough Rows with specific values from 2 Columns
I have some code that is working, but not completely.  This code is taking values that are input into a Form.  From there it looks to see if those values are found in Columns B and D.  If they are both present, then the entire row has a strikethrough applied.
My issue is that once it finds a match, it isnt able to find another match if the user launches the form again.  It believe the FoundCell variable I have isnt resetting, it is holding the range from the intial run.
Of the 2 values being searched, the values in Column B can be repeated, but the value in Column D would be unique.  So I think once it finds the first example of B & D both being present and then doing the strikethrough, it is incapable of finding another B & D because the find function already found an A.1. in column B.
Dim A1 As Integer
Dim sec1 As String

'''A.1.
If sec1x = True Then   '''This is a checkbox on the form
    sec1 = "A.1."      ''' this is the value in column B
    A1 = A1x.Text      ''' this is the value that is searched for in Column D
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim findWS As Worksheet
    Dim findRng As Range
    Dim findStr As String
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim rowrng
    
    Set findWS = ActiveSheet
    Set findRng = findWS.Range("B3:B" & lrow)

    findStr = sec1
    
    Set foundCell = findRng.Find(what:=findStr, LookIn:=xlFormulas, MatchCase:=False, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set rowrng = foundCell
        If foundCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = A1 Then
            rowrng.EntireRow.Font.Strikethrough = True
        End If
        MsgBox foundCell.Row '''This was a test, that once its done the foundcell row doesnt change
End If


If the Col D value is unique then look for that first and then check col B

Didnt work, I should clarify.  Values in Column D are not unique entirely.  Example, Column B has Multiple values of A.1.  And the values in column D are numerical.  So Column B looks for value A.1. and then in column D it looks for the value 3.  Finds both, strikethrough.  The next search may look for A.2. in column B, then look for the value of 3 in column D.  I am trying to strikethrough unique combination of values in column B and D.  But it seems to fail at any repeat of either individual value as opposed to the unique combination of them both.

Something like this should do it:
Dim A1 As Long, sec1 As String
Dim lrow As Long, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, arr
Dim findRng As Range, r As Long

If sec1x = True Then   'This is a checkbox on the form
    
    sec1 = "A.1."        ' this is the value in column B
    A1 = CLng(A1x.TEXT)  ' this is the value that is searched for in Column D
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set findRng = ws.Range("B3:D" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    arr = findRng.Value 'read range data to array
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)    'loop over array rows
        If arr(r, 1) = sec1 Then   'check colB value
            If arr(r, 3) = A1 Then 'check colD value
                With findRng.Rows(r).EntireRow
                    .Font.Strikethrough = True
                    .Columns("N").Value = "N/A"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End If


Thank you so much!  Follow up to this, how would I make it so that in addition to the strikethrough, the code would also add the value "N/A" to column N?  I was trying to add the offset function to findRng but that was adding the value to multiple columns and the entire column, not just the cell within the same row as the found values of A.1.

See edit for adding "N/A"
